# Collapse flexbox column on mobile

Tags: css, flexbox

I've got two columns (using flexbox) and a media query breakpoint. However I've tried the following css attributes to get the columns to be 100% and stack on top of each other when on mobile.

Currently remains as a column, side by side at all times.

width: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;

**Code for the container**

```
.flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

**The code for the columns**

```
.flexbox-column {
  display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flexbox-column {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #444;
  }
}
```

My codepen (I don't know how to get the 'Run Code' feature to work on here)
https://codepen.io/jordanc26/pen/yjWZQJ

Comment: .flexbox-column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .flexbox-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving this rule

```
  .flexbox-container {
     display: flex;
  }
```

into the mediaquery scope is enough:
in fact, for narrow viewports, both your column elements are not in a `flexbox` container anymore, so they will stack on top of each other and they will extend for the entire available width

> [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLoeXQ)